# How to remove primary key constraint from SQL Server with table name only

Tags: sql, database, constraints, primary-key, mssql-jdbc

I want to remove primary key constraint from a table `mytable`.

In Mysql we can remove primary key constraint like

```
ALTER TABLE *mytable* DROP PRIMARY KEY
```

How to do this in SQL Server?

Thanks for the reply in advance. :)

**NB**: I have a list of tables in SQL Server to remove primary key constraint. Is there any default name for primary key constraint

```
create table mytable 
(
     column_a integer not null,
     column_b integer not null,

     primary key (column_a, column_b)
);
```

Comment: I think the default name of the **PK** constraint in a table is `PK_tableName` if you design via SSMS NewTable design feature.

Comment: Thanks @KnockKnock So the following statement will work. Is it? ;          String q_str="ALTER TABLE "+my_table+" drop constraint PK_"+my_table;

Comment: Yep, that should work if `nameOfConstraint` is correct. Have you find out your _Name_ of the PKConstraint? Using SSMS, you can find it by right clicking the **Table**, click _Design_. Then in Design tab, right click _Row_,choose _Indexes/Keys_ and in the _Indexes/Keys_ window you can view list of PK etc. constraints there. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do this in SQL Server - not without first determining the **name** of the PK constraint. If you would be giving **explicit** names to your primary key constraints based on a fixed naming schema - then maybe you could do it using the table name only.... but not if you let SQL Server handle the naming itself....

You can determine the name of the PK constraints from the `sys.key_constraints` catalog view, and if you run this query, 
you'll get (as output) as list of `ALTER TABLE ..... DROP CONSTRAINT .....` commands that you can then use to drop all
the constraints on your tables:

```
SELECT 
    'ALTER TABLE ' + SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.Name + 
    ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + k.name
FROM 
    sys.key_constraints k
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables t ON k.parent_object_id = t.object_id
WHERE 
    k.type = 'PK'
    AND t.Name IN ('myTable', 'myTable2')   -- etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for ur valueable answer. Is the following query is correct?                         ALTER TABLE 'my_table' DROP CONSTRAINT (SELECT k.name FROM sys.key_constraints k INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON k.parent_object_id = t.object_id WHERE k.type = 'PK'
    AND t.Name ='myTable')

Comment: @apm: no, you cannot do it like that - you will need to find the name of the PK first, and then you would have to use **dynamic SQL** if you want to build your SQL statement with that PK name and execute it. You cannot "parametrize" table, column or constraint names with sub-selects or SQL variables.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for ur reply